# Wordpress media button "insert into post" not returning file url

Tags: php, wordpress

[image]I have created a custom field where media file url/location is stored using wordpress standard media gallery pop up by clicking "insert into post" button. Below is my code to extract the path of the media file. Image url is working fine. But it is returning only media title. I don't know where can I get the file path from.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#wsp_media_button').click(function() {
     formfield = jQuery('#wsp_media').attr('name');
     tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?TB_iframe=true&amp;tab=library');
     return false;
    });

    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
        var imgurlar = html.match(/<img[^>]+src=\"([^\"]+)\"/);
        var imgurl = imgurlar[1];

        //html is returning only title of the media
        alert(html);

        //image
        if( imgurl.length ){
            jQuery('#wsp_media').val(imgurl);
        }
        //other types of files
        else{
            var fileurl = jQuery(html);

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user has **not** selected to include a link URL when inserting media (video, pdfs etc) then all that is passed back into the editor is the file name, which is what you are seeing.

If you wanted to always ensure that the file URL was sent back, regardless of what settings the user has chosen, or store the file URL in a different format you can hook into two seperate filters.

Procedural setup:

```
    add_filter('media_send_to_editor', 'media_to_editor', 1, 3);
    add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'image_to_editor', 1, 8);
```

For images, the filter function looks like the below:

```
image_to_editor($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt){

}
```

For media attachments:

```
function media_to_editor($html, $send_id, $attachment ){        

}
```

So, you could, within those filters change the adjust the data getting sent back to the editor to make sure it always has the file URL. For media attachments, check to see if the html includes a file reference, and if not, add it back, and send that back to the editor.